# apply css linear-gradient on P tag to style each line differently

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

if you read long articles or post on the internet, you get lost sometimes when you move your eyes form the end of the line looking of the next line. it happens to me so i though of coloring the beginning and ending of lines where the the end of the line and the start of next line have the color. keeping visual track.
here is an example of what i mean: [link](http://mutaz.info/easr/index.html) (view link on wide screen, won't be helpful on mobile view)
in CSS i want to apply line-gradient horizontally to p tag where

1. each line has three colors (one on left, transparent in the middle and another color on right)
2. repeat three colors patterns for every three line

what i found it doable so far is zebra-like strips with only one color
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW2ss.png)

what i wish to have
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2JVr.png)

any idea on how to do that? I appreciate your help guys.

Comment: what you have do for that?

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you open that page, you exactly have what you want? Open the code and look into it?

Comment: @JeroenE if you open that page you will see that each line is defined with a gradient, it's not a dynamic solution as it's not responsive and you are obliged to have a ton of gradient

Comment: @JeroenE exactly as Temani Afit said

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can consider `repeating-linear-gradient` and multiple background. You repeat a gradient on the left and another on the right and you use a third one to create a separation in the middle and simulate the transparent part:

```css
p {
  line-height:1.2em;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right,transparent,#fff 30% 70%, transparent),
    
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      red   0    ,red   1.2em,
      blue  1.2em,blue  2.4em,
      green 2.4em,green 3.6em) 
    left/50% 100% no-repeat,
    
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      orange 0    ,orange  1.2em,
      pink   1.2em,pink    2.4em,
      purple 2.4em,purple  3.6em) 
    right/50% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis, mi eget euismod faucibus, ligula sem suscipit tortor, ut rutrum dui augue et urna. Maecenas quis diam lectus. Mauris tempus enim finibus dolor pulvinar commodo. Aenean auctor tortor sit amet venenatis ultricies. Pellentesque condimentum quam sapien, non sagittis nulla molestie eu. Morbi nec orci convallis, tempor elit sed, scelerisque arcu. Quisque vel luctus erat.
</p>
```

[image: Multiline CSS gradient]

As you noticed the `line-height` is important here so we can consider CSS variable to make this more flexible:

```css
p {
  line-height:var(--l,1.2em);
  background:
    linear-gradient(to right,transparent,#fff 30% 70%, transparent),
    
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      red   0                     ,red   calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),
      blue  calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),blue  calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),
      green calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),green calc(3*var(--l,1.2em))) 
    left/50% 100% no-repeat,
    
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      orange 0                     ,orange calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),
      pink   calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),pink   calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),
      purple calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),purple calc(3*var(--l,1.2em))) 
    right/50% 100% no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis, mi eget euismod faucibus, ligula sem suscipit tortor, ut rutrum dui augue et urna. Maecenas quis diam lectus. Mauris tempus enim finibus dolor pulvinar commodo. Aenean auctor tortor sit amet venenatis ultricies. Pellentesque condimentum quam sapien, non sagittis nulla molestie eu. Morbi nec orci convallis, tempor elit sed, scelerisque arcu. Quisque vel luctus erat.
</p>

<p style="--l:2em;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis, mi eget euismod faucibus, ligula sem suscipit tortor, ut rutrum dui augue et urna. Maecenas quis diam lectus. Mauris tempus enim finibus dolor pulvinar commodo. Aenean auctor tortor sit amet venenatis ultricies. Pellentesque condimentum quam sapien, non sagittis nulla molestie eu. Morbi nec orci convallis, tempor elit sed, scelerisque arcu. Quisque vel luctus erat.
</p>
```

[image: different gradient each line CSS]

To have transparency we can consider a `mask` and pseudo element:

```css
p {
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
  line-height:var(--l,1.2em);
}
p::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      red   0                     ,red   calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),
      blue  calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),blue  calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),
      green calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),green calc(3*var(--l,1.2em))) 
    left/50% 100% no-repeat,
    
    repeating-linear-gradient(to bottom,
      orange 0                     ,orange calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),
      pink   calc(1*var(--l,1.2em)),pink   calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),
      purple calc(2*var(--l,1.2em)),purple calc(3*var(--l,1.2em))) 
    right/50% 100% no-repeat;
  -webkit-mask:linear-gradient(to right,#fff,transparent 30% 70%, #fff);
  mask:linear-gradient(to right,#fff,transparent 30% 70%, #fff);
}

html {
  min-height:100%;
  background:linear-gradient(#e2e2e3,#f2f2f3);
}
```

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis, mi eget euismod faucibus, ligula sem suscipit tortor, ut rutrum dui augue et urna. Maecenas quis diam lectus. Mauris tempus enim finibus dolor pulvinar commodo. Aenean auctor tortor sit amet venenatis ultricies. Pellentesque condimentum quam sapien, non sagittis nulla molestie eu. Morbi nec orci convallis, tempor elit sed, scelerisque arcu. Quisque vel luctus erat.
</p>

<p style="--l:2em;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec facilisis, mi eget euismod faucibus, ligula sem suscipit tortor, ut rutrum dui augue et urna. Maecenas quis diam lectus. Mauris tempus enim finibus dolor pulvinar commodo. Aenean auctor tortor sit amet venenatis ultricies. Pellentesque condimentum quam sapien, non sagittis nulla molestie eu. Morbi nec orci convallis, tempor elit sed, scelerisque arcu. Quisque vel luctus erat.
</p>
```

Comment: It's nice, but it's not transparent in the middle

Comment: @HerrSerker I wanted to use different color so we can clearly see both gradient, using the same won't help visually (then the OP can adjust like he want)

Comment: Orange, pink, purple looks better then red, blue, green